# How to add a checkbox to every group header using Infragistics XamDataGrid (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I would like to add one checkbox to every group header, and the handle its click or change event using Infragistics XamDataGrid. In the event I must know a) what is the state of the checkbox and b) for what group it belongs to.

(Ideally the solution would be MVVM as so far I managed to solve all issues using pure MVVM, but this requirement seems to be a luxury to me currently. I would be *extremly* happy if I any solution could put this checkbox there and I can handle the event in code behind.)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Correctly answered by Infragistics forum:

[How to add a checkbox to every group header? (and handle click/change event)](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/91922/454297.aspx#454297)

Thanks for all who spent time with this.